# How to draw rounded corner polygons on android canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, polygon, rounded-corners

I need to draw polygons like triangle, trapezoid, pentagon, parallelogram, rhombus etc. It seems Path class is way to go, however i need these polygons have rounded corners and i also need to control the amount of the rounding.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Find below a simple example to draw rounded corner polygons (i.e. triangle, rectangle, etc.)

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {            
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    float radius = 50.0f;
    CornerPathEffect corEffect = new CornerPathEffect(radius);
    paint.setPathEffect(corEffect);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(20, 20);
    path.lineTo(400, 20);
    path.lineTo(600, 300);
    path.lineTo(400, 400);
    path.lineTo(20, 400);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

In order to control the amount of rounding, change the value of radius.